# How to use UIActivityIndicatorView on custom UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to use UIActivityIndicatorView on my custom UIButton.

Here is my code:

```
if (sender.tag == 1) 
{
    // Start animating
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    // Check if the network is available
    if ([self reachable]) {
        // Stop animating
        activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
     }
  }
```

What I want to do here is: 
Once the user touch the button, I want to start the ActivityIndicatior while Reachable checking the network availability. Once it done pass it to the next view.

**Update**
UIActivityIndicator is on top of my custom UIButton. It build successfully, but ActivityIndicator is not showing when I touch the button.

Comment: did you ever add it to your view?

Comment: well the interface is kind of complicated, that's why I want to use in on the button.

Comment: Exactly. Did you ever add the activityIndicator to your button? (e.g. in `-viewDidLoad` on your button `[self addSubview:activityIndicator]`

Comment: Yes, I do have a IBOutlet for the activityIndicator. I connected in the nib file. Which the ActivityIndicatory is on top of the UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you had your answer since then. 
After 4 years, language has changed to Swift, but I had the same problem : UIActivityIndicatorView is not showing when I add it through :

```
    self.myButton.addSubview(self.myIndicatorView)
```

I had to climb a level up :

```
    self.myButton.superview!.addSubview(self.myIndicatorView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct in your project, the problem here is that you're showing and hiding an activity indicator in the same event loop, without giving a pause to draw it.  Let me explain:

If you have the code:

```
UIView* view = someView; 
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// various synchronous operations

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

The view will only ever have a background color of yellow.

To answer your question, you probably want to animate the spinner, do some asynchronous operation, then stop the animation.  The key being to not stall on the main event loop while your asynchronous task is running.  If your comfortable with blocks it would look something like this:

```
if (sender.tag == 1) {

    // Start animating
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    // Check if the network is available
    [self checkReachableWithCallback:^{
        // Stop animating
        activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }];

}
```